# OSGi path error with Jzy3d/JOGL (gluegen-rt not found)

Tags: java, opengl, osgi

I am currently working on some OSGi application and I wanted to use the library Jzy3d to display 3D graphs. Basically, this library leverage opengl for java (JOGL ?).

I have added a specific bundle including all the jars needed to run Jzy3d and exporting all org.jzy3d.*.
From an other bundle, I try to use the library but at runtime, executing `Chart chart = new Chart();` throws the following exception :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gluegen-rt in java.library.path
```

At the beginning, I thought it was due only to the different classloaders of the different bundles so I moved the failing lines in a "Util" class inside the library bundle that I now call from the other bundle.
However, it didn't change anything : I got always the same error about gluegen-rt.

I have checked that gluegen-rt.jar is in the bundle classpath of the "library bundle". It is also included in the binary build (as all the other needed jars).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.library.path` is the path to native libraries, so I assume you either didn't set it or some library is missing. Check what native libraries JOGL needs for your OS and architecture and provide a path to them.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I guess I was mistaken at some basic point due to the use of native libraries !

Answer (score 1):

Another (and maybe better) suggestion: as of jogl2 rc5 (or maybe little earlier), native libs are packed in jars. I could have the windows jar work on my computer without setting any runtime directory for dlls, so you may make your own jogl bundle from http://jogamp.org/deployment/archive/rc/v2.0-rc5/ if you don't have time to wait for a jzy3d update. See a related discussion: http://forum.jogamp.org/FileNotFoundException-td3654307.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a suggestion for eclipse developpers on the download page of www.jzy3d.org. Alternatively you may drop native libs in your jre/bin folder

Comment: Putting native libs in jre/bin will work but is incredibly bad practice =(

Comment: Why is it bad? If I'm not wrong java3d binaries go there at install.

Comment: +1 for your other answer.  Dependencies should be managed as part of the app's deployment not as part of the platform.